# cable losses per meter (voltage > 400 and frequencies [50 Hz ... 60 Hz])

Tags: cables, power-electronics, dielectric

If I compute

I * I * R

I obtain the loss of the conductor in Watt. Is this per meter similar to the dielectric loss (see IEC 60287-1-1)?

I am also wondering about the loss factor of sheath and screen (see IEC 60287-1-1). Do I multiply this factor with the conductor loss (I * I * R) to obtain the loss of the sheath and screen?

Comment: Is "R" the resistance of a certain piece of cable with a fixed length, or a value in Ohms / meter (or km) of a cable which might be built to any length?

Comment: See: http://www.engineeringexpert.net/Engineering-Expert-Witness-Blog/?p=3423 I think I just answered the first part of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Dielectric loss is an AC concept. It sounds like you are dealing with RF current, which is bound by much more complicated laws than DC.

Ohm's law only tells a very small part of the story once you get to frequencies where dielectric loss is an issue. Cable resistance loss and dielectric loss are two totally separate things.

Also, above a few KHz, the resistance of a cable changes because the skin effect makes the current only use the outside and not the middle of the conductor.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I should have made this clearer but I was talking about voltage > 400 and frequencies [50 Hz ... 60 Hz]. I have edited the question.